# Z score data by column in R

Tags: r, centering, standard-deviation, normalize

Below is a small, simplified version of my dataset. This data has already been log2 transformed. I would like to use the standard deviation to see how far each element is from the SD, treating each column as its own.

I was wondering if this line here would work

`scale(logdata, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)`

```
              A                B              C               D               E
R1      -0.434836671    -0.108772638    -0.000674938    -0.333749912    -0.608165885
R2      -0.072168631    -0.285296255    0.024473        -0.326715632    -0.882788114
R3      -0.54414254     -0.269099509    -0.016684508    -0.028660542    -0.236927454
R4      -0.762881846    -0.054663207    -0.016672169    -0.038475666    -0.462750221
R5      -0.079776401    -0.176689481    0.087003362      0.131840424    0.109491763
R6      -0.172537433    -0.092644342    0.015477811      0.027402294    0.078664283
R7      -0.422822576    -0.105579631    -0.03750016      0.003756128    -0.014107015
R8      -0.27263471      0.032882775    -0.076755456     0.042560642    0.013867512
R9      -0.149443092     0.03019628     -0.039934703    -0.003320687    -0.205039037
R10     0.106705796      -0.027710203   0.089172743     -0.068607332    0.121851149
```

Comment: @PLapointe ; scale works on the full data ie it does apply separately for each column

Comment: Yes, as @user20650 points out, `scale` operates by column on full data already, so @JakeeIn, your command should work as you think

Comment: @user20650 , ChiPak You are both right.

Comment: from *"use the standard deviation to see how far each element is from the SD"*, I dont think the result of `scale` in your question will  provide this, but `scale(logdata, center=sapply(logdata, sd), FALSE)` would, (although i dont know why this would be done)